# How do I resolve this error: expected unqualified-id before '-' token

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, parameter-passing, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Context: Preparing for the Fall semester, I whipped up a quick code file to check if you can call a function as a parameter of another function. However, before I could compile the code and check - this error happened.

> C:\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g
> \wsl$\kali-linux\home\tyrael\Foundry\morga.cpp -o
> \wsl$\kali-linux\home\tyrael\Foundry\morga.exe
> '\wsl$\kali-linux\home\tyrael\Foundry'
>
> CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
>
> UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
>
> In file included from
> C:/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
> from \wsl$\kali-linux\home\tyrael\Foundry\morga.cpp:1:
>
> C:/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ostream:681:49:
> error: expected unqualified-id before '-' token
> __rvalue_ostream_type<_Ostream>>::type -    operator<<(_Ostream&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
> ^
>
> Build finished with error(s).
>
> - The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).
> - Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

I had tried moving around the #include  statement, didn't work.

I tried to isolate the cause of the error by commenting out huge swaths of the code, but the error still there.

My only guess as far as what the issue could be is that the compiler is **very angy** that I am trying to call a function as a parameter for another function, but I can't verify that.

I'm truly at a loss, I just don't know what it could be. Any help would be much appreciated!

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

int combiner();
int multiplier(int target_sum);

// Forward declaration of my functions

int combiner() {

    int input1 = 5;
    int input2 = 10;
    int input3 = 15;
    int sum = input1 + input2 + input3;

    return sum;
}

// simple function that takes numbers and combines them into one total sum

int multiplier (int target_sum) {

    int big_sum = target_sum * 5;

    return big_sum;
}

// simple function that takes a number and multiples by 5

int main (int argc, char** argv) {

    combiner();
    int final = multiplier(combiner());

    cout << "This is our final number: " << final;

    return 0;
}

// putting it all together, using a function as a parameter for another function
```

I remembered that you can't pass a func as a parameter for another func in C, but you can in other langs. However, even when I get rid of that process - I still hit the error. Here's the new code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

int combiner();
int multiplier(int target_sum);

int combiner() {

    int input1 = 5;
    int input2 = 10;
    int input3 = 15;
    int sum = input1 + input2 + input3;

    return sum;
}

int multiplier (int target_sum) {

    int big_sum = target_sum * 5;

    return big_sum;
}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {

    int tiago = combiner();
    int final = multiplier(tiago);

// Storing return value of combiner() into a int variable, using that var as 
// parameter instead for 2nd function - multiplier

    cout << "This is our final number: " << final;

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: In the vein of investigating my compiler, here are some screenshots to show what my compilation process looks like on VS Code.

[Selecting the compiler type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5H8q.png)

[Select the actual compiler, the one I want is g++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajqHP.png)

Comment: `int final = multiplier(combiner());` is 100% legal and couldn't result in the reported error no matter how hard you tried. I can't produce any errors with the given code.

Comment: Make sure you haven't accidentally edited a library header or declared a very unfortunate macro you've left out of the question. `__rvalue_ostream_type<_Ostream>>::type -    operator<<(_Ostream&& __os, const _Tp& __x)` suggests the former. that `-    ` shouldn't be there

Comment: there is no restriction to use returned values of functions in C as parameters - are you sure you are trying to compile C code? it seems from your error message that you are using GCC for cpp -In file included from C:/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39, from \wsl$\kali-linux\home\tyrael\Foundry\morga.cpp:1:

Comment: @user4581301

Yeah, I can confirm that all the code you see in the question is all the code I have in the file. Not one line of code was omitted. I haven't attached / created any header files, this is just a straight .cpp file that I want to compile. If I knew how to attach screenshots in a reply comment, I would 100% show you.

Comment: @JoshKuber

Hmm, I think you're on to something here. I had written that code file in VS Code, which admittedly - I have not used in a couple months, and it does seem that something has changed with my compiler. Certain settings weren't remembered, and now I'm running into this issue. As far as I know, I am using a g++ compiler to compile the code on VS Code.

I had hopped into my Kali Linux distro on WSL to compile the file, and both versions of the file had passed compilation. So the issue does seem to be compiler based. Thanks for that insight.

Comment: Just posted screenshots of my compiler process in VS Code if that helps at all.

Comment: Recommendation: Check the modification timestamp on C:/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ostream . If it's not really close to the other headers around it something may have stomped the file. Occasionally while debugging  I'll find the debugger drops me into a library file and an errant keypress gets in. One save all open documents later, your library implementation is corrupt, leading to bizzarro problems like this. When installing the compiler and tools try to install them so that you can't modify them (read and executable permissions only) to prevent this.

Comment: If you can confirm C:/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ostream contains that errant minus sign, remove it and try to build again. It might be the only problem. Otherwise reinstalling might be the fastest option.